# Why does RPAD() on a Date column return only the date component?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a column in a table with a data type as `DATE`. When I fetch the column via a query (I've used `SYSDATE` as an example, but the behavior is the same), I get the date/time - which I understand.

```
SELECT SYSDATE
FROM DUAL

SYSDATE
--------------------
21-Feb-11 12:24:39 PM
```

Now, using `rpad()` returns only the date part

```
SELECT SYSDATE, RPAD(SYSDATE, '9') 
FROM DUAL

        SYSDATE        | RPAD(SYSDATE, '9') 
 ----------------------|-------------------
 21-Feb-11 12:27:14 PM | 21-FEB-11
```

[Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm) states:

> RPAD returns expr1, right-padded to length n characters with expr2, replicated as many times as necessary. If expr1 is longer than n, then this function returns the portion of expr1 that fits in n.

Now `sysdate` returns characters > 9, so why doesn't, say `rpad(16)` return the date and the time ?

```
SELECT SYSDATE, RPAD(SYSDATE, '16') 
FROM DUAL

        SYSDATE        | RPAD(SYSDATE, '16') 
 ----------------------|-------------------
 21-Feb-11 12:27:14 PM | 21-FEB-11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RPAD is a string function, so when you apply it to a DATE value Oracle first has to implicitly convert the date to a string, which it does using the session's default format mask, which usually does not include the time component.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, RPAD (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-Mon-YY HH:MI:SS'), 16)
FROM DUAL;
```

Having said that, you **are** getting the time when you just select SYSDATE.  If I try to replicate your case I see this:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS';
SQL> select sysdate, rpad(sysdate,16) from dual;

SYSDATE            RPAD(SYSDATE,16)
------------------ ----------------
21-FEB-11 11:20:20 21-FEB-11 11:20:
```

i.e. pretty much what you were hoping to see.  Which makes me wonder: how are **you** setting the format so that SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL shows the time?

Comment: That makes sense. Re: how are you setting the format - just checked - SQL*Plus returns only the date, while my IDE ( PL/SQL developer) returns date+time - under IDE settings however - I've instructed it to use Oracle settings. Querying `v$nls_parameters` for `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` returns `DD-MON-RR` under my IDE as well as under SQL*Plus @TonyAndrews